# Watir: how to open a set of webpages in multiple tabs in IE9 or FF or Chrome?

Tags: watir

I have a script that opens multiple URLs.  Currently these URLs open in completely separate browser windows.  I would like to open them in a single browser window with multiple tabs.  I can use IE9 or the latest Chrome of Firefox.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I tried some things out, but I could not figure out a way to invoke a second tab through the API. I was able to set the IE tab settings to open links in a new tab. Then I created a page that had a link to a second page. When that link target="_blank", the second page opened in a new tab. Beyond that, I have no ideas.

What problem are you trying to solve with multiple tabs that wouldn't be solved with two browser instances?

Good luck,

Dave

Comment: In my scenario, I visit a page that has a form.  I need to enter different sets of data into that form and I would like to see the results of each set of data in a different tab in the same browser window/instance. Opening multiple browser windows is not really a problem, rather it's an annoyance.

Comment: If you just want to see the form after it's filled out, that's not really an "automated" test. I empathize, none the less. I think it's OK to have partially automated tests. Maybe you can take advantage of screen capture to review your filled in forms later? Watir has a class for that - Watir::ScreenCapture

Comment: My use of Watir in not in test scenario rather as a user who's trying to optimize a website that I visit regularly.  I'm using Watir as an end user to save me the tedium of mouse clicks.